# É possível clonar objetos no Delphi?

Tags: delphi

É possível clonar objetos no Delphi em tempo de execução?

Por exemplo, tem um *Data Module* com uma `zTable`. Se eu usar essa `zTable` em duas telas ao mesmo tempo, com filtros diferentes, a segunda tela irá sobrepor o filtro usado pela primeira.

É possível eu usar essa `zTable` como modelo e no `onShow` do meu form eu criar um *clone* dela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo as dicas do @Gunar Bastos consegui encontrar uma solução para o meu problema. Segue abaixo:

```
function CopiarDataSet(zTableOriginal: TDataset): TJvMemoryData;
var
    i:integer;
begin
    //Abrindo o dataset original
    zTableOriginal.Open;

    //Criando o clone e copiando a estrutura do original
    Result := TJvMemoryData.Create(Application);
    Result.CopyStructure(zTableOriginal);

    //Abrindo o clone
    Result.Open;

    //Movendo o cursor para o primeiro registro do dataset original
    zTableOriginal.First;

    //Iteração para copiar os dados do original para o clone
    while not(zTableOriginal.Eof) do begin

        //Preparando o clone para receber os dados
        Result.Insert;

        //Iteração sobre os campos da tabela
        for i := 0 to zTableOriginal.FieldCount - 1 do begin
                //Copiando os dados
                Result.FieldByName(zTableOriginal.Fields[i].FieldName).Value := zTableOriginal.Fields[i].Value;

                //Copiando os labels das colunas
                Result.FieldByName(zTableOriginal.Fields[i].FieldName).DisplayLabel := zTableOriginal.Fields[i].DisplayLabel;
        end;

        //Efetivando a inserção
        Result.Post;

        //Indo para o próximo registro do dataset original
        zTableOriginal.Next;
    end;

    //Fechando o dataset original
    zTableOriginal.Close;

end;
```

Answer (score 6):

Dependendo da classe, dá sim...

Tente criar em tempo de execução uma zTable e use o comando:

```
        zTableCriada.Assign(zTableOriginal);
```

Deixe te explicar: O Assign serve para obter 'em tese' todos os dados de outro componente da mesma classe e copiá-los para ela mesma, em sua instância. O problema é que isso não é automático; Quando o programador da classe em questão a está escrevendo (no caso, o desenvolvedor da zTable), ele deve manualmente programar o procedure Assign, ou então dará erro de 'não implementado'. Então, vai de fazer um teste, pois não tenho aqui os componentes instalados.

Se não der certo, há várias formas de fazer o que você quer. Qualquer coisa te dou umas idéias aqui.

Comment: Caso não funcione, use os métodos do TClientDataSet

Comment: Entendi... Caso a `procedure` `Assign` não tenha sido programada, eu conseguiria criar um `Helper` para os meus `TZtable`, seguindo a mesma lógica do método `Assign`?

Comment: Sim. Tudo depende de quais propriedades você vai usar. Por exemplo, para pegar os dados, copiar a propriedade SQL e em seguida dar um Open já bastaria; Mas você provavelmente vai querer pegar DisplayLabel's dos campos, formatação de casas, etc... Aí seria só fazer uma procedure que faça a cópia de tudo o que você precisa. Detalhe é que no geral, tudo o que vc vai precisar estará concentrado nos Fields. Fazer um loop com eles repassando tudo de um campo para outro resolveria.

Answer (score 5):

Se o desejo é simplesmente clonar objetos o Delphi suporta isso através do método TPersistent.Assign que é o ancestral da classe TComponent, que serve de base para os componentes visuais e não visuais do Delphi.

Este método pega o conteúdo de um objeto (o passado por parâmetro) para o novo, e ficaria algo no seguinte estilo

```
procedure ClonazTable(zTableOriginal: TDataset);
begin
  zTableClonada.Assign(zTableOriginal);
end;
```

Outra opção é clonar objetos através de Rtti, percorrendo o objeto e copiando os dados de um para o outro. Existe um artigo bom sobre o assunto na revista CLube Delphi número 113.

Contudo como este componente é uma consulta ao banco de dados, as informações que são trazidas do banco não serão clonadas junto. Para fazer isso é necessário copiar toda a estrutura do dataset para algo que existe exclusivamente em memória, como um TClientDataset.

Para fazer isso, é necessário copiar primeiro a estrutura e depois os dados do DataSet original para o DataSet em Memória, duas das muitas opções que existem para facilitar este trabalho são:

***1. TJvMemoryData***: Um Componente do pacote Jedi (que é free), ele tem um método que copia a estrutura de um Dataset para o componente, deixando apenas com o trabalho de copiar os dados.

```
function CopiarDataSet(zTableOriginal: TDataset): TJvMemoryData;
begin
  Result := TJvMemoryData.Create(Application);
  **Result.CopyStructure(zTableOriginal);**
  zTableOriginal.First;
  while not(zTableOriginal.Eof) do
  begin
    ***//Código que copia os dados***
    zTableOriginal.Next;
  end;
end;
```

***2. TdxMemData***: Um Componente do pacote da Developer Express (que é pago), ele tem um método que copia completamente o Dataset para um novo.

```
function CopiarDataSet(zTableOriginal: TDataset): TdxMemData;
begin
  Result := TdxMemData.Create(Application);
  **Result.CopyFromDataSet(zTableOriginal);**
end;
```

Comment: Legal Gunar Bastos... já utilizo o Jedi no sistema que estou desenvolvendo... vou tentar implementar a primeira alternativa.

Só fiquei com uma dúvida, dentro do `while`, onde devo copiar os dados, tenho que fazer assim:


`Result.FieldByName('meu_campo').value := zTableOriginal.FieldByName('meu_campo').value`


?

Comment: Isso mesmo @ThiagoThaison, ou se desejar deixar a função mais genérica pode iterar pelo `zTableOriginal.Fields` e usar `Result.FieldByName(zTableOriginal.Fields[i].FieldName).Value := zTableOriginal.Fields[i].Value;`

Comment: Rapaz, funcionou certinho! Valeu...

Answer (score 4):

Neste caso não será possível para você fazer a clonagem do conteúdo do zTable (assumindo que seja um componente Table do Zeos), pois é um componente cujo conteúdo é recuperado diretamente do servidor de dados.

No seu caso, melhor seria ter baseado a tua implementação (na verdade, toda a tua aplicação) no componente `TClientDataset`. Este componente sim permite que seu conteúdo seja clonado, de forma a fornecer a funcionalidade que você precisa, que é ter os mesmos registros já selecionados em um outro contexto, pra outro uso, sem interferir no componente original.

No teu caso específico, minha melhor sugestão é estudar o `TClientDataset` e o `TDatasetProvider` e assim reformar o teu `DataModule` para fazer uso deste componente. Então você adicionará um método `Clone` neste `DataModule` que vai produzir a réplica dele para ser usada no outro local sem interferir na instância original.